# Promise resolution

Tags: javascript, web, nativescript

I am new to javascript promises, I am using below code from NativeScript to query sqlite database and just want to return `true` if row exists and `false` otherwise:

```
function hasBookmark(url) {
    (new Sqlite("pakjobs.db")).then(db => {
        db.all("SELECT url FROM bookmarks WHERE url=?", [url]).then(rows => {
            return rows.length ? true : false;
        }, error => {
            console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
            return false;
        });
    }, error => {
        console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
        return false;
    });

    return false;
}
```

However function ALWAYS returns `false`.

Can anybody tell how do I return `true` if row exists and `false` otherwise ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function hasBookmark(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (new Sqlite("pakjobs.db")).then(db => {
            db.all("SELECT url FROM          bookmarks WHERE url=?", [url]).then(rows => {
                resolve(rows.length ? true : false)
            }, error => {
                console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
                resolve(false);
            });
        }, error => {
            console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
}

hasBookmark(url).then(function(isValid){
   If(isValid){
     // Do something
   }
});
```

Comment: Apologies, was trying from iphone 5s , a bit difficult to do formatting from phones , but yeah have edited the answer.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to be able to return true or false, that's pretty much the point of Promises, you can't return something asynchronously in javascript.

What you can do, however, is directly returning the Promise you're creating and then calling `.then` on it.

```
function hasBookmark(url) {
    return (new Sqlite("pakjobs.db")).then(db => {
        return db.all("SELECT url FROM bookmarks WHERE url=?", [url]).then(rows => {
            return rows.length ? true : false;
        }, error => {
            console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
            return false;
        });
    }, error => {
        console.log("hasBookmark ERROR", error);
        return false;
    });

}

const hasBookmarkPromise = hasBookmark('someurl');

hasBookmarPromise.then(value => {
    if (value === true) {
        console.log('has bookmarks');
    }
});
```

Comment: I did how you told, it still returns `false` always :(

Comment: You will also need to `return` the inner promise from the first `then` handler

Comment: Yep, forgot about the inner promise. Thanks!